# why JPA can save my entity but It can't delete the entity?

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0

In my JSF2-JPA2-Spring3 project, I can insert new entities but can't remove entities. This is the error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance entity.Entity#8

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>            
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>   
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my service:

```
@Service("myService")
```

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

```
@Resource(name="MyRepository")
MyDAO myDao;

@Transactional
public void deleteEntity(Entity entity) throws DAOException {
    myDao.delete(entity);
}
```

This is my dao:

```
@Repository("MyRepository")
```

public class UserDAO{

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public void delete(Entity entity) throws Exception {

    try {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

This is applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >

        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit"/> 
</bean>

<bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />     
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<tx:advice id="transactionInterceptor" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut=" execution(* service.*Service.*(..))"
        advice-ref="transactionInterceptor" />
</aop:config>
```

I try to remove an entity from a list that feed using this method in dao:

```
public List<Entity> getAll() throws Exception {
    List<Entity> list = null;

    try {
          list = entityManager.createQuery("Select e from Entity e").getResultList();
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you that the entity you are trying to delete can't be deleted because it isn't associated with the current persistence context. This can happen if you read the entity in one transaction and then try to delete (or update it) in another transaction, because the persistence context is scoped to the transaction.

To fix it, change your DAO to first merge the entity back into the persistence context, then delete it:

```
Entity newEntity = entityManager.merge(entity);
entityManager.remove(newEntity);
```

Note: EntityManager.merge() returns an entity that is part of the current persistence context - the entity you pass in is still detached.

Comment: Thanks. But when I do this: entityManager.merge(entity);
                   entityManager.remove(entity); the same error occured!

Comment: I cleaned up my code sample to make it more readable. Read the note again - you can't call merge on an entity and then remove that same entity, you have to use the entity that gets returned from merge().

Comment: Thank you. Now it works correctly, but is there any method in this config So I don't have to merge my entity first to do a dao operation on my entities? I feel that it is not best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can delete your entity with a bit of JPQL:

```
public void delete(Entity entity) {
    em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Entity e WHERE e.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", entity.getId())
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm trying something like org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter but it doesn't work :-( I don't know why?!

Comment: I'm trying to use org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter but it doesn't work for me. Also, somewhere I saw that folk say using an open database connection in view pattern is not always a good solution when it comes to performance and memory efficency. If so, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Sounds like Spring is getting in your way. The most obvious alternative is that you just don't use it. It's a much less relevant framework that it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that can be:

```
Entity newEntity = entityManager.getReference(Entity.class, entity.getId());
entityManager.remove(newEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some tutorials around for Generic DAO implementations:

```
public void delete(T entity) {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}
```

I got the same *Removing a detached instance entity error*, so I changed it to:

```
public void delete(T entity) {
    T eT = entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.remove(eT);
}
```